# Shortest way to sort that array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'action_operator' => string 'by_fixed' (length=8)
      'action_amount' => string '10.0000' (length=7)
      'sort_order' => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      'action_operator' => string 'by_percent' (length=10)
      'action_amount' => string '10.0000' (length=7)
      'sort_order' => string '1' (length=1)
  ...
```

I want to sort that according to the sort_order key starting with the lowest (0 in this case). I know I can iterate and so on, but whats the shortest code to achieve that?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why you need the shortest code and not the most readable or the most efficient?

Comment: Have you looked at the php built in function [ksort — Sort an array by key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)?

Comment: I am just interested in how to solve that :)

Comment: Using usort() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

usort( $aData, function( $a, $b ) {
  return ($a['sort_order'] < $b['sort_order'] ? 1 : -1);
} );
```

With PHP7 you should be able to use the spaceship operator:

```
usort( $aData, function( $a, $b ) {
  return $a['sort_order'] <=> $b['sort_order'];
} );
```

Comment: You should switch `1` and `-1`, otherwise the array will be sorted in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner using usort:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['sort_order'] - $b['sort_order']; });
```